# Updating multiple rows in mysql with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

**[I have folliwing PHP file](http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/8AkTw/)**

which is creating this table:

**[Table createb by PHP with MySQL data](http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/SBKB2/5/)**

Every row have two inputs.
My DB table has AUTO_INCREMENT 'ID' field.

How can I update my DB Table and make sure that rows will be updated accordingly to the ID's (auto incremented field)?

**I'm must admit that SQL with PHP is very new to me and I don't know is this correct way of doing it?**

```
            $news_SQLupdate = "UPDATE news SET ";   // table name is 'news'     
            $news_SQLupdate .=  "LIVE= '".$LIVE."', ";
            $news_SQLupdate .=  "CONTENT= '".$CONTENT."', ";
            $news_SQLupdate .=  "WHERE ID = '".$ID."' ";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By including the id in the WHERE clause?

```
UPDATE <someTable> SET ... WHERE id = <someId>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your update statement, you will need a where id=(the id number)

Simple example:

```
UPDATE table_name set field1=value1 where id=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `tblContent` SET `On/Off` = true WHERE (`ID` = 1 OR `ID` = 2)
```

Dynamicaly add a `OR ID = X` in the where clause to apply the changes to another record.

Answer (score 0):

"UPDATE table_name SET column_name1=' value[$array]', column_name2=' value[$array]' WHERE column_name=' value[$array]' ";

Answer (score 0):

I tried this one state above:

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET column_name1=' value[$array]', 
    column_name2=' value[$array]' 
WHERE column_name=' value[$array]' ;
```

Just confirming that it worked for me perfectly.